# how to configure backup wamp server?

Tags: wamp

I have hosted an intranet website on WAMP server which is working as expected. Now i would like to configure a backup site to it. I mean if it goes down by any chance how do i counter that?

My challenge is i can not have the URL changed as its already been distributed to many users in the past.

My URL is like

> http  :/  /ipaddress/MyProject/Running/Index.html

I want to know, how do i have a backup website running on the same url to maintain high availability?

Answer (score -1):

Since WAMP applications do not provide their own backup APIs, you need to stop all services if you want to take a full file-system level backup; otherwise you'll get a lot of "file locked" errors and/or your backups will be in an incoherent state.

So yes, you can just make a copy of your C:\wamp directory, but stop all your WAMP-related services before (and remember to restart them after).

any problem please comment me...)

Comment: Did you read anything other than the word "backup" in the question? This isn't answering what was asked.

Answer (score -1):

use a slave server with the one using as a master not sure of the tech but I know windows allows two or more servers with same info on them both.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).